# How can I STunnel/multiplex RDP and HTTPS over the same ServerIP:443?

Tags: tls, proxy

I need access to my own RDP running outside of a network with DPI-firewall.
So SSL is the only option, but I have a SSL web server running.
As I have as well only a single IP adress with dynamic IP I am looking to achieve something like the following with Stunnel:

```
[client-side] rdp --> stunnel-client --------->rdp/ssl https://abc.com ----> [stunnel server] --> rdp ~ Win Client 192.168.1.123:321
                      + user-certificate???

[client-side] web browser --------------------->https/ssl https://abc.com --> [stunnel server] --> http ~ www server 192.168.1.555:80
```

Explanation:
On the local machine I would point rdp to the stunnel which would present the individual user-certificate and the server side would know to send the traffic to server 192.168.1.123 on port 321.
But if a web browser would open abc.com the server side would present the http(s) website as there was no individual user certificate existing. So a fast check would bring only the official https web site.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this.
sslh works perfectly but will not prevent detection by DPI as rdp would only use 443.
Now I was checking stunnel.
It's SNI aware, but will not help either (e.g. rdp.abc.com versus abc.com)
It seems I can only use one service (https OR something else).

ON the other hand it has the option redirect = [HOST:]PORT to send all traffic to the http web server in case the certificate was not accepted (by using verify=3 + user-certificate)

Will this work with in my case (and esp. with rdp), any other option to achieve 443 ssl protocol sharing (obfuscating).

Comment: Try using a Websocket tunnel instead, see [google search: websocket tunnel firewall](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+tunnel+firewall). This should blend in with most DPI firewalls because it is actually HTTP(S).

Comment: O.k. thanks for your comment, will try and check - do you know one where I can split 443 or 80 to different IP adresses/ports on the server.
Was looking e.g. at Softether, which works as well (Socket and others) with GFW in China. But I am not sure if I can use it without admin rights on the client side...

Comment: "...do you know one where I can split 443 or 80..." - I have no idea about your environment but with iptables such things are doable. Nevertheless, this is a different question and off-topic here too.